# LMS algorithm python

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement LMS algortihm, I am reading this paper: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf 
I am stuck at the update step of theta ( page 5 in the paper ).
Especially, what I am trying to do, is to add two numbers. I am giving a testX, which is a nx2 matrix and a vector testY, which is a n-dimensional vector. The aim of the learnTheta algorithm is to find such theta as to minimze the cost function using that specific theta. In this case, the optimal theta is [1,1], so the algorithm should make theta converge to this vector. Unfortunately, it does not. I would appreciate any help.

```
import numpy as np
import math

def hypothesis(x, theta):
    """
      x is training set
      theta is weight parameter
      """
    return np.transpose(np.array(theta)).dot(np.array(x))

def costFunction(theta, x, y):
    """
        x is training set => (j, 2)
        y is a vector of
        theta is weight parameter
        """
    factor = 1 / 2
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        sum += math.pow((hypothesis(x[i], theta) - y[i]), 2)
    return factor * sum

def learnThetaSingle(theta, x, y, alpha):
    return theta + alpha * (y - hypothesis(x, theta)) * x

def learnTheta(theta, x, y, alpha):
    f = theta
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        f = learnThetaSingle(f, x[i], y[i], alpha)
    return f

testX = np.array([[1, 2],
                   [4, 6],
                   [5, 123],
                   [41, -14],
                   [-413, 0],
                   [0, 0],
                   [5, 12],
                   [-3, -14],
                   [1, 1004],
                   [51, 51]])

testY = np.array([3, 10, 128, 27, -413, 0, 17, -17, 1005, 102])
theta = [2, 3]
print(costFunction(theta, testX, testY)) 
# 2147656.0
theta = learnTheta(theta, testX, testY, 0.0001)
print(theta)
#[-29.59330648  68.71968433] , this is far from true
```

Comment: This means that costFunction(thetaOptimal, x, y) should be 0 (as long as there is enough test data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, the problem was that the old algorithm goes through the whole data set only once, but now it iterates through all the data set each time a value i in theta from (0, len(theta)) is updated. That would be O(len(theta)*len(data set)) complexity. That's a batch gradient descent (according to Andrew Ng)